# Any ideas to pursue music as career

Tags: guitar, voice

Putting cover videos on youtube/instagram for a while but not growing,any other ideas to pursue music as career.

Comment: The usual ways seem to be a) session music, b) teaching, c) playing gigs, but you have to be pretty good for all of those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a career out of music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/how-to-make-a-career-out-of-music)